# Componente hijo no importa Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

tengo el siguiente inconveniente.

El usar un componente hijo, no puedo utilizar ningún componente de Angular Material.

Como se puede solucionar?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ 
path: 'cliente/:ninp10/:clipot/:mesa', 
component: PageClienteComponent, 
canActivate: [LoginGuardService],
children: [
  { path: 'perfil', component: PerfilClienteComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuardService] }
 ] 
},
```

Hasta el componente PageClienteComponent, no tengo problemas. Pero en el componente PerfilClienteComponent no me reconoce nada de Angular Material.

**Ejemplo**

En la imagen, la barra de la izquierda es un sidenav del componente padre. Dentro hay un `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` donde está el componente hijo que se supone que es un `mat-card` (con la imagen del perro).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que error te sale? Pones la ruta correctamente para que el match con la ruta definida en el routing? Yo creo que es mas bien tema de rutas que no es la misma y no carga tu componente

Comment: No sale ningún error. Simplemente, al entrar al componente `PerfilClienteComponent` no aplica los estilos ni componentes de Material.

Comment: has importado los módulos de material en tu `app.module` o en el modulo que tengas tu componente?

Comment: Sí, están importados. Tengo un `material.module.ts` donde importé todos los componentes que necesito de Material. Y está importado en el `app.module`. Eso anda, porque tengo la aplicación así y funciona. El problema están en el componente hijo que agregué. Ahí dejó de funcionar, solamente en ese componente. Como si no estuviera siendo importado.

Comment: es muy raro si tienes importados los modulos de material.

Comment: Podrá ser que estoy yendo desde el componente `PageClienteComponent` hacia el componente `PerfilClienteComponent` a traves de: `this.router.navigate(['perfil'], { relativeTo: this.rutaActiva });` ?

Comment: No. Si te carga el componente inspecciona la consola a ver si falta alguna clase o directiva de material

Comment: No lanza ningún error en consola. Simplemente no tiene importado los componentes de Material. El el parent sí los tiene. No puedo adjuntar imagen aquí. Lo agrego en la publicación.

Comment: Estas important un tema de materia? pareciera que hacen falta los estilos